# Enviar String con Ajax en net core 6

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvc, datos, texto

Tengo una situación con el siguiente AJAX que no me envía los datos, la variable "concat" esta llena e incluso la veo con un alert antes de entrar al AJAX

```
concat += result.join(' ').split(' ', 1) + 'a';
});
} if (concat != '') {    
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Producto/Exitoso",
    data: concat,
    contentType: "text/plain",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (res) {
        $("#ProductosAddPartial").html(res);
        $("#productoModal").modal('show');
}
});


y este es mi controlador como lo recibe

 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Exitoso(string id)
```

Comment: Pone un ejemplo de esos datos que tiene `concat`

Comment: allí lo actualicé, lo que hace esa variable es concatenar unos Id's con una letra para luego leerlos.